# My computer accidentally went to sleep while running Spyder - can I continue my script or do I need to restart?

Tags: python, spyder

I have Windows 11 and I'm running a script in Spyder that takes 40 hours to complete - at the 10 hour mark my charging cable got loose and the laptop went into sleep mode

When turning it back on, spyder continues the calculation as normal

However, I'm using a seed to make my calculation replicable and want to publish the results

Is it save to continue or should I restart the script?

Comment: Well, if you're publishing, you really should be running the calculations multiple times to make sure everything agrees. Continue the run now, note the results, run it several more times, and compare everything.

Comment: You need to supply more detail about how the seed is used - is it just an input to deterministic calculations made by your code, or do you use it to initialise an external random number library? In the first case I would expect that if the code keeps running after waking from sleep then the variables in its workspace will not have changed; in the second case, it is possible that something could have been reinitialised by sleeping and waking. Either way, you could maybe check by writing a minimal example (that takes less than 40 h to complete).